# Run docker container in Azure DevOps

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I faced recently issue while trying to implement scanning pipeline for images in Azure ACR repository using Trivy.

I created Service connection to ACR and tried commandline taks:

```
steps:
  - task: Docker@2
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: "CompanyACR"
      command: "login"
- task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: Trivy Image Scan
    inputs:    
      script: |
        echo "##[group] Image Vulnerability Scan (LOW,MEDIUM)"
        docker run \
        --rm \
        -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
        -v $HOME/.cache/trivy:/root/.cache/ \
        -v $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/templates/junit.tpl:/root/junit.tpl \
        -v $PWD:/work/ \
        --env GITHUB_TOKEN \
        aquasec/trivy \
        --light \
        --no-progress \
        --severity LOW,MEDIUM \
        --ignore-unfixed \
        --format template \
        --template "@/root/junit.tpl" \
        -o /work/junit-report-low-med.xml \
        $(imageName):$(tag)
        echo "##[endgroup]"

        echo "##[group] Image Vulnerability Scan (HIGH,CRITICAL)"
        docker run \
          --rm \
          -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
          -v $HOME/.cache/trivy:/root/.cache/ \
          -v $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/templates/junit.tpl:/root/junit.tpl \
          -v $PWD:/work/ \
          --env GITHUB_TOKEN \
          aquasec/trivy \
          --light \
          --no-progress \
          --severity HIGH,CRITICAL \
          --ignore-unfixed \
          --format template \
          --template "@/root/junit.tpl" \
          -o /work/junit-report-high-crit.xml \
          $(imageName):$(tag)
        echo "##[endgroup]"
```

I got following error:

> 2021-07-01T15:59:24.614Z  FATAL   scan error: unable to initialize a
> scanner: unable to initialize a docker scanner: 3 errors occurred:    *
> unable to inspect the image (***/azure-vote:v1): Error: No such
> image: ***/azure-vote:v1  * unable to initialize Podman client:
> no podman socket found: stat podman/podman.sock: no such file or
> directory     * GET
> https://***/oauth2/token?scope=repository%3Aazure-vote%3Apull&service=***: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required, visit
> https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.

I can reproduce similar error running from az without login.
I tried Docker task as well but with the same outcome:

```
steps:
  - task: Docker@2
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: "CompanyACR"
      command: "login"

  - task: Docker@2
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: 'CompanyACR'
      repository: $(imageName)
      tags: $(tag)
      command: 'run'
      arguments: >
        --rm 
        -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
        -v "/home/vsts/.cache/trivy:/root/.cache/" 
        -v $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/templates/junit.tpl:/root/junit.tpl 
        -v /home/vsts/work/1/s:/work/
        aquasec/trivy 
        --light 
        --no-progress 
        --severity LOW,MEDIUM 
        --ignore-unfixed 
        --format template 
        --template "@/root/junit.tpl" 
        -o /work/junit-report-low-med.xml 
        $(imageName):$(tag)
```

I assume that if Service connection is used at least Docker Run task should work.
Any idea why I am getting authentication errors and how to make it working.

Standard configuration without docker works fine:

```
steps:
- script: |
    sudo apt-get install rpm
    wget https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/releases/download/v$(trivyVersion)/trivy_$(trivyVersion)_Linux-64bit.deb
    sudo dpkg -i trivy_$(trivyVersion)_Linux-64bit.deb
    trivy -v
  displayName: 'Download and install Trivy'

- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'CompanyACR'
    command: 'login'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: "Run trivy scan"
  inputs:
    script: |
     - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: "Run trivy scan"
      inputs:
        script: |
            trivy image --severity LOW,MEDIUM --format template --template "@templates/junit.tpl" -o junit-report-low-med.xml $(imageName):$(tag)         
            trivy image --severity HIGH,CRITICAL --format template --template "@templates/junit.tpl" -o junit-report-high-crit.xml $(imageName):$(tag)
```

You might be questioning why I am asking when there is working solution, just for curiosity why it is not working and to understand authentication within docker container.
Thanks in advance for any ideas how to further investigate...

Comment: Can you use a `container` resource instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-containers

Comment: I think this is more for scenario when I would like to run container using ACR image. In my case I want to run trivy image from public registry and only access images in ACR to do the scanning.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, which was caused by missing ACR registry prefix, which I assumed would not be needed as the image was built locally on the same CI pipeline. Anyways, I would suggest you to add the Azure Container Registry prefix to the image name i.e. 'myregistry.azurecr.io/azure-vote:v1'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).